# How do I compare and modify characters with corresponding indices from two strings?

Tags: python

For example:

```
string1 = 'ABC'
string2 = 'xBz'
for a, b in string1, string2:
    if a == b:
        print 'True'
        a = (a.upper())
        b = (b.upper())
    else:
        print 'False'
        a = (a.upper())
        b = (b.upper())
print 'new string1 =', string1
print 'new string2 =', string2
```

I want to be able to compare the strings character by character and then modify the characters based on whether they are the same or not. I have tried using zip() but that resulted in tuples, which couldn't be modified (if I understand correctly).

Comment: *modify the characters based on whether they are the same or not* - how should they be modified(according to your example) ?

Comment: You cannot modify strings in-place like you can with lists. You will have to construct a new string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this:

```
s1 = 'abcdef'
s2 = 'axcyez'

l1 = list(s1)
l2 = list(s2)

for i, item in enumerate(zip(s1, s2)):
    if item[0] == item[1]:
        l1[i] = l2[i] = item[0].upper()

s1 = ''.join(l1)
s2 = ''.join(l2)
```

`zip()` is used to form tuples of elements from `s1` and `s2`

`enumerate()` is used to track indexes of each string characters

**Output:**

```
>>> s1
'AbCdEf'
>>> s2
'AxCyEz'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a new string that contains all the elements that string1 and string2 have in common you can use this code:

```
print "".join([x for x in string2 if x in list(string1)])
```